# Link rule_1 output targetting files with rule_2 input targetting the files' folder [snakemake]

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to create a workflow in snakemake with two rules:

- `pool_files` that creates, from a list of genomes saved in different folders, a copy of each genome into a same folder
- `run_pairwise` that takes the path of the folder containing the genome copies, runs a function (in my case in ANI calculation, but is not relevant) and save all the results in a output folder

My issue is that input and output of the first rule `pool_files` are single files, while the input and output of the second rule `run_pairwise` are folders. My workaround is to provide both the copied files of `pool_files` and the output folder of `run_pairwise` as inputs for `rule all`, however, in the best case scenario, I am getting an error like:

> ChildIOException: File/directory is a child to another output

The table (object `gnm_table` in the example below) that I read in and that contains the path of all genomes looks like this:

```
                  dir          file
0  _input/genomes/ref   aaa_v1.0.fa
1      _input/genomes        bbb.fa
2      _input/genomes        ccc.fa
3      _input/genomes        ddd.fa
```

While a temptative code that I came up with so far looks like this:

```
import os

rule all:
    input:
        expand("_results/pool_gnms/{target}", target=gnm_table.file),
        "_plots/ANI"


rule pool_files:
input:
    i_gnm = lambda wildcards: os.path.join(gnm_table.dir[gnm_table.file == wildcards.target].to_string(), wildcards.target)
output:
    gnm_link = "_results/pool_gnms/{target}",
shell:
    'ln -s '
    '{input.i_gnm} '
    '{output.gnm_link}'


rule calculate_ANI:
input:
    pool_dir = "_results/pool_gnms",
output:
    ANI_dir = directory("_results/ANI")
shell:
    'average_nucleotide_identity.py '
    '-o {output.ANI_dir} '
    '-i {input.pool_dir}'
```

What strategy should I follow to accomplish this task? Maybe I should use a checkpoint?
Many thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in checkpoints. Checkpoints are needed when you don't know the files that a rule would create (e.g. you don't know the number of clusters that the algorithm finds). In your case you have everything you need in the `gnm_table`. You may define a rule that claims all files that need to be copied in `rule pool_files` as its input. The output of this rule may be a [flag](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#flag-files), and this flag could be an input for `rule calculate_ANI`.